# How to automatic display info window on Google maps?

Tags: javascript, maps, infowindow

I currently have a google map on my website, it has the event "click" for every infowindow. So if you click on a marker, the infowindow will pop up. But, I want the infowindow's to display automatically, without having to click on them first.

This is my code, can someone help me out?:

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                // Maps zoom level 16
                zoom: 16,
                // Start location
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.996098, 5.891174),
                // Map style
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            });

            // info window
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            // Markers
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],       locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }



            function clickroute(lati, long) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long);
                map.panTo(latLng);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatically'? One for every marker that is added?

Comment: I already have one for every marker, but I want them to display without having to click on it..

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create a marker, also create an info window and open it:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infoWindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: I actually don't know how to implement it on my code

Comment: The map is working now, but the markers are gone and no infowindow is displaying automatically. I need to click for it just like i did it before.